# Transfer Verified identities one organisation into another organisation in AWS SES

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

Currently, I am using Verified identities in one AWS organization and I am planning to copy/transfer to another AWS organization so is there any way to proceed with this transfer?
If Transfer is not possible ,any other way to achieve this

Comment: Are you going to move accounts between AWS Orgs? https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/organizations-move-accounts/?nc1=h_ls

Comment: NO , Move only Verified identities in SES one AWS org to another AWS org @shimo